# Trigonometry: Writing $\csc{x}$ in terms of $\cos{x}$

Tags: trigonometry

Trying to write $\csc x$ in terms of $\cos x$. Please tell me what I am doing wrong:

Step 1: Use reciprocal identity

$$\csc x= \frac{1}{\sin x}$$

Step 2: Square both sides

$$\csc^2x= \frac{1}{\sin^2x}$$

Step 3: Apply Pythagorean identity

$$\csc^2x = \frac{1}{1-\cos^2}$$

Step 4: Obtain the square root of both sides

$$\csc x=\pm\sqrt\frac{1}{1-\cos^2}$$

The correct answer is supposed to be:

$$\csc x=\frac{\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}{1-\cos x^2}$$

Comment: I'm sure you mean $1-\cos^2(x)$ on the denominator. $\cos(x^2)$ is completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done nothing wrong except forgetting to write an [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function) for $\cos^2(\cdot)$. This may seem trivial, but you should not forget to do this since this could be problematic if you have an equation with multiple variables/parameters.

---

I will start from Step 4. Note that the numerator and denominator are both positive for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore:
$$\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\cos^2(x)}}=\pm \frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}}=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}}$$
Here's the part you probably missed. Note that you can multiply both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}$. Hence:
$$\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}}=\pm \frac{\color{green}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}}}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}\cdot {\color{green}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}}}}=\pm \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}}{1-\cos^2(x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

We can say $$\pm\sqrt\frac{1}{1-\cos^2x}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}$$

We can then [rationalise the denominator](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/rationalize-denominator.html) to give us $$\pm\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}{1-\cos^2 x}$$